# Sharing Cookie Between Server Side ASP.NET MVC Microfrontends

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am developing an application that uses micro-frontends approach using ASP.NET MVC. As a result, I have multiple .NET MVC applications that each have their own frontend and backend, and I am redirecting between them when a user for instance clicks a button.

This can be shown like this:

[image: Architecture] (Courtesy to: [Klee Thomas's blog](https://dev.to/kleeut/how-do-you-share-authentication-in-micro-frontends-5glc) ).

**IMPORTANT!**

However, in my scenario, the routing looks slightly different. I will be using Admin API and People API as my main targets.

My main app is **Admin API**, so it currently has no path base. The People API has a path base `/people`

**Authentication**

I am using an external service to authenticate and then use Cookies that are being sent with every request to allow the users to perform the action.

**Error Scenario**

By default (and this might be wrong) I am using the same cookie name.

**No Reverse Proxy testing**:

I deploy my two applications on different ports (localhost:XXXX and localhost:YYYY)  When I navigate to any of them, the cookies are created at the root path (**/**) and the applications by themselves work just fine.

When I try to test the interaction between the two (Let's say that an Admin API would redirect to People API), the following thing happens:
Firstly, I am getting too many redirects error, but after a sec the Chrome refreshes and I am successfully redirected.

In my cookies, at this point I only have cookies with **/** path.

**Reverse Proxy**

However, in my target environment, I will be using reverse proxy. So, I am using Nginx and I have built the proxy successfully. In case, the Admin API has to talk to People API, it would not hit directly, but it would use the Reverse Proxy.

So when I am trying to test this scenario upon redirect I am hit in the face with:

Request or cookie too large scenario: the app doesn't redirect further and I am stuck and I need to clean my cookies to proceed.

The DevTools shows me one set of cookies for **/** path and another for **/people**. As a result, I have an error page, 6 entries in my cookies tab:

1. Path /; Value: number of Cookies Chunks; Name: identity
2. Path /; Name: identityC1
3. Path /; Name: identityC2
4. Path /people; Value: number of Cookies Chunks; Name: identity
5. Path /people; Name: identityC1
6. Path /people; Name: identityC2

**Code**

This is the piece of code shared between all apps and I think the code error is somewhere here:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(delegate (AuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Cookies";
    }).AddCookie(delegate (CookieAuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "identity";
        //options.Cookie.Path = $"/{cookieName}";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/access-denied");
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/signin");
        options.ReturnUrlParameter = "redirectUri";
        options.Events.OnSigningOut = async delegate (CookieSigningOutContext context)
        {
            //SHARED CODE
        };
    }).AddOpenIdConnect("OpenId", //CODE
    );
```

**What I tried**

1. Give a different cookie name:

   ```
   options.Cookie.Name = $"identity{appName}";
   ```

   This results in a similar error, yet I can clearly see which cookie is which.
2. Set Cookie Path explicitly on the cookie

   As a result, this unfortunately results in the same error. I assume the reason is that because the main app still uses "/" and the other app uses "/people", but yet all of the cookies are being sent.

   This seems to be also confirmed by this:
   https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28734
3. Add a prefix to the main app and use Cookie path.

   This actually seems to be working. When I am on my main app I see Cookies for /admin. When I navigate to my other app, I see cookies for /people. (Although I am not fully convinced that login redirects are fully working as I don't have currently access to Auth provider)

Questions:

**1.** Am I missing something or it has to be done the way I have done in attempt 3?

**2.** Obviously this has a drawback that every application has its own "logging" mechanism and it's own cookie, so sending anything explicit from one app to another (such as "User agreed to all cookies!" must be done using some other explicit script).

**3.** Is there any better architecture for such scenario?